# Тестирование UI Automation на iPhone

Tags: ios, macos, uiautomation

Почему когда я пытаюсь воспроизвести свой тестовый JavaScript, тестовое приложение запускается на iPhone, но затем сразу "сворачивается"?

К примеру, запускаю простейший скрипт:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
target.frontMostApp().logElementTree();
```

На iPhone приложение запустилось и сразу стало неактивным (не закрылось, а именно стало неактивным). При этом в лог ничего не записалось.